# to remove the appended element from scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have uploaded the multiple pdf file in angular js. Here I have tried to append the selected files as follows

```
<input type="file" class="md-input dropify" id="inputs" multiple required ng-model="gFiles" ngf-multiple="true" ng-files="getTheFiles($files)"/>
    $scope.getTheFiles = function (index,$files)
    {
        var len = 0;
        for (var value of $scope.WaiveFormData.values())
        {
            len++;
        }           
        for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('inputs').files.length; i++) 
        {
            $scope.WaiveFormData.append("Attachement" + len++, 
            document.getElementById('inputs').files[i]);
        }   

    };
```

If I remove the particular items from selected list it remains same in the `$scope.WaiveFormData` . How to remove the selected item from the appended `$scope.WaiveFormData`  . Pls help me to solve this

Comment: try using $element.remove(); $scope.$destroy();to remove element completely.

Comment: I dont want to remove entire elements completely. To remove only the selected elements as do in $scope.imagename.splice(index, 1);